# how turn off speculative execution in hadoop source code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hadoop2

I need to turn it off in hadoop source code ,and I can not find its package in eclipse.
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setReduceSpeculativeExecution%28boolean%29

Comment: why you need source code for this? you can turn off speculative execution by this configs: `mapreduce.map.speculative` and `mapreduce.reduce.speculative`

Comment: I need the name of the package and class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable Speculative Execution, add these properties in `mapred-site.xml`.

```
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.map.speculative</name>
   <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.reduce.speculative</name>
   <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Or at the Job level, set the properties in the Driver class.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set(“mapreduce.map.speculative”,false);
conf.set(“mapreduce.reduce.speculative”,false);
```

For its source code refer these: [hadoop-mapreduce-project](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/master/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/app/speculate), [Job](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/master/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.java) and [JobConf](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/master/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.java)